# UITableView scroll to index is broken

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch

I have implemented indexing in my `UITableView` by implementing the two methods, `sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:` and `tableView:sectionForSectionIndexTitle:atIndex:`. It worked at first, but I noticed, after a few weeks of development later, that it is now broken.

To be more precise, I am still getting the latter event fired whenever I touch an index on the side, and it will return the correct index, but the table is not jumping to that section, nor will a call inside the latter function to explicitly scroll down to that section (in the form of `scrollToRowAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:`) do anything remotely resembling scrolling.

Does anyone know what could go wrong here? I know there's not much information available...I am positive it was working before.

Some code snippets

```
...

indexList = @[@"A", @"B", @"C", @"D", @"E", @"F", @"G", @"H", @"I", @"J",
              @"K", @"L", @"M", @"N", @"O", @"P", @"Q", @"R", @"S", @"T",
              @"U", @"V", @"W", @"X", @"Y", @"Z", @"#"];
...

- (NSArray *)sectionIndexTitlesForTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return indexList;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
    sectionForSectionIndexTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSInteger)index {
    return index;
}
```

Even more interestingly: I think it is caused by having a second search table sharing the delegate with the original table! The indexing works with the search table but not the original table...

Any comments would help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very intriguingly, it seems like when we define an index for the `UITableView`, the view that displays the index is *not* a subview of the table view.

I was relying on setting the alpha value of the search table to fade it in/out to toggle between search and non-search modes, unaware that the index view of the search table is covering the original table.

If anyone else runs into this problem, try use `bringSubviewToFront:` instead of changing alpha!